# How is the newline, tab characters represented in purescript?

Tags: printing, tabstop, purescript

For eg.
How do I print out something like this:

```
showEntry entry = entry.lastName ++ "\t" ++
                  entry.firstName ++ "\t" ++
                  entry.phone
print(showEntry {lastName: 'Doe', firstName: 'John', phone: '555-555-5555'})
```

This just prints out `Doe\tJohn\t555-555-5555`.

Comment: How are you running this function? If you are using `psci`, the `Show` instance will escape the tab character, which is why you see `\t` in the output.

Comment: Yes, I am using `psci`. That explains it. I think you mention that in the book somewhere. Can I make sure the "\t" is not escaped during print, like preventing the Show instance's standard behavior? Or by using a different function altogether instead of `print`?

Comment: The call to `print` is baked into `psci`. You could hack in a call to `console.log` with an unsafe FFI primitive: `foreign import unsafeTracing "function tracing(x) { console.log(x); return x; }" :: forall a. a -> a`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question was based on an old version of the language and associated tools. Nowadays, this is what you can do.

Use `log` from `purescript-console` (https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-console/4.2.0/docs/Effect.Console#v:log).

```
> import Effect.Console
> log "Hello\tSailor!"
Hello   Sailor
unit

>
```

The REPL (purs repl) uses `show` implicitly to encode values as strings. To get around this, one can use the log effect (as Phil Freeman mentioned in his comment, though there is nothing unsafe about using `log`).